# ADVAPI32.dll error when launching Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, dll

I've been getting the following warning message when launching Visual Studio 2010 recently:

"The procedure entry point EventUnregister could not be located in the dynamic link library ADVAPI32.dll"

I can't remember what programs I've installed recently that would cause this issue. I'd like to track it down and get rid of the warning. Thanks.

Comment: What version of Windows are you using?

Comment: Windows XP Professional Version 2002 SP3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm betting you installed the VS 2010 Diagnostic Tool, which (apparently) doesn't work under XP, and seems to replace/corrupt the ADVAPI32.dll.

See the 'reviews' tab here: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/e8649e35-26b1-4e73-b427-c2886a0705f4/

Here's one of the reviews:

> I installed it before having read that it isn't usable on XP. After deinstalling, i still got the entry point error and was still not able to debug my (C++) projects because of an NtClose error right at the start of a debug session.
>   I only got rid of it via a reset to a system restore point.

So you may want to figure out if/when that tool was installed (Add/Remove Programs should tell you) and roll back to a restore point from before you installed it.

Comment: Hi techie007, Thanks much for the info. Yes I bet you are right. But how do I "figure out if/when that tool was installed (Add/Remove Programs should tell you) and roll back to a restore point from before you installed it"? Is there a step-by-step instruction somewhere? Much appreciated!

Comment: Start->Control Panel->Add/Remove Programs is what I was suggesting. :)

Comment: Hi techie007, Thanks for the reply. I've found this link (http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/using/helpandsupport/learnmore/systemrestore.mspx) to be helpful. Unfortunately, I didn't have any restore point created at the time I installed the Diagnostic Tool.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this by removing the following file:
C:\WINDOWS\system32\Microsoft.Internal.Performance.CodeMarkers.dll

Supposedly it´s something loaded with VS 2010 that uses the EventUnregister-method in advapi32.dll that doesn't exist in versions prior to Vista.

I can´t say that there´s no side effects to doing this but so far it works.

Found the solution here:
[Reviews - Visual Studio 2010 Diagnostics Tool](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/e8649e35-26b1-4e73-b427-c2886a0705f4/view/Reviews)